Effective Strategies for Ice Age Monster Hunters?
Background
My world is an earth-like planet called Torenthelm, where metals are much rarer than they are on our Earth. The planet's winters last around 300 of their days, so during the winter the people can be considered an "ice age" society.
Because of metal's rarity, their technology is roughly similar to Earth's own Stone/Ice Age. IE, they use spears and bows with stone or bone arrows for their hunting weapons.
The Problem
Let me introduce the Vrelniik: A draconic creature about as smart as an orca and partially covered in feathers to keep warm during the planet's harsh winters.

The Vrelniik hunt in packs of three to five.
They measure from roughly 11 to 23 feet long, and at shoulder height are roughly six feet tall when fully grown.
Their canine teeth are around 6 inches long and 2 inches wide at the base.
Their tails are prehensile, with spines along the edge of the last six vertebrae that stick out from their skin.
They utilize chemicals stored in bladder-like organs near their throats to release a stream of 'ice'.

Notably, stone/bone spears/arrows can't pierce Vrelniik scales because of how durable the aforementioned hides are are and because hunters commonly can't get close because of the beasts' size, speed, tails, and the ice attack. One tactic deemed semi-effective was attacking in groups, but even then there were mass casualties.
Competing with the Vrelniik for territory is a tribe of humanoid wolves, called the Chitrant. The Chitrant created a small group of hunters dubbed the 'Valenguard' to patrol their territory. The Chitrant's territory is similar to  Alaska.
Question
What tactic or weapons can the stone/ice-age Chitrant successfully use to compete against the Vrelniik while minimizing casualties?

This Q has a high likelihood of being closed because it's basically asking for a list on a service that expects one-specific-question/one-best-answer. We regularly close "what's the best X for Y?" questions because they're incredibly circumstantial (what resources/opportunities/knowledge/time/season/people/etc. are available?) Our stone-age ancestors faced this question and had a variety of methods to deal with it. Have you not researched what they did? I'll get your research going with a hint.

"...can't pierce the hide of the monsters because of reasons" - without telling us what those reasons are we have no way to advise on what weapons might work.  Note that this is additional to the issues in the question listed by @JBH

I find it hard to believe that stone arrow and spear points - which were and still are among the sharpest man-made objects ever made - can't pierce the skin of a mere large animal.  With an arrow- or spear- shaft behind them, that has Newton's Impact Depth Approximation right behind it, with the advantage that they'll cut their way in.  Humans have cut down trees with stone axes... what makes your critters' hides tougher than that?

Well, there's usually a vulnerable point. Eyeballs, inside the mouth or up the nose would seem to be nice targets for poison arrows. Getting them to open their mouths on cue is the tricky bit.

If you could, please divide your text in paragraphs for readability. Now, you mentioned that speed is a factor for not being able to hunt something, but that hardly matters as humans are endurance hunters. The only thing that matters is getting in that first strike from ambush and getting the animal to bleed. Just chase it until it falls over dead/exhausted. Traps are another way to avoid the problem of animals being to quick. @Escapeddentalpatient. Leaving out poisoned bait could work too. That said, poison often ruins (parts) of the meat, or requires special preparation considerations.

Pit traps have been used for large game. If your planet has a 900 day warm season the winter is still only 1/4 of the year.  Ice and desert planets have no air due to lack of photosynthesis which is a sad oversight un many Sci-Fi universes.

High speed means spears work wonderfully if you use them right. Consider why pike square tactics worked against traditional cavalry, it’s not because the soldiers could jab at the cavalry, it’s because the cavalry couldn’t charge into the pikes without impaling themselves or their horses. Spears can be used exactly the same way if you set them up in a choke point and force/trick the target into going through that choke point at high speed.

Reg. "about as smart as a troodon": Kinda problemativ to compare a quality of an imaginary creature with that of a extinct one. How smart were troodons ? Comparable to a current day mammal, like a lion or wolf ?

Comparable to modern creatures, Vrelniik are around as smart as an orca, not a troodon.

A couple of points:
1)   If your winter is 300 days long, your other seasons have to expand out to match otherwise any large animals are going to die off due to starvation. The thing is the sun powers photosynthesis, which in turn feeds the rest of the food chain all the way to the top. Using Earth as a template? Very few large animals overwinter in Polar regions, and those that do are tied to oceans for food supplies.  Your humans would be too if they stayed put. Most other large animals instead migrate with the seasons and it's only when you go further south and it starts to get warmer that you see more species staying put all year round.
2)   Spears will still be good. But you're not throwing them; you're 'setting' them. You pick your terrain (choke points are good) and you 'encourage' the monsters to charge. The animal's own weight then ensures the spear runs it through. Think boar spears. Not for the fainthearted but they worked. Sharpened wooden stakes buried in the ground around your villages/camp sites would serve the same purpose defensively. Lastly, regardless of the above, charging into the flank/vulnerable points of an animal using a spear with your full body weight behind it has also been proven in the past to be an effective killing method. (Some paleo-anthropologists think this was Neanderthal Man's primary killing technique for large game.)
3)   Bows and arrows are still good because poison is a wonderful thing. Kalahari bushmen for example while small in stature use poison arrows very effectively to bring down large game. Failing that, you can simply 'bait' predators by poisoning a carcass and leaving it on or near game trails or other areas a selected predator often uses. If you've got the right poison, you can also sometimes bait herbivores as well but you generally need more of it to cover a broader area/volume of whatever their preferred food is.
4)  Traps and dead falls are also still good, especially because you don't have to be right there on the spot when an animal falls into whatever  snare or pit trap it is that kills or captures them. Do some research on the  various types of trap that have been used in the past. There are many ingenious and highly effective traps that humans have used through the ages to hunt both small and large game.
5)   Fire. Animals fear it, humans like it. So in the right circumstances and with the right planning it can aid hunting parties by deterring predators from charging or causing stampedes in directions the hunters want the prey to go - like off a cliff or into a pit or enclosure.
EDIT: I am taking your statement claiming that spears and bows can't 'pierce' the animals hides to mean they usually can't pierce them deeply enough to inflict fatal injuries and NOT that that they can't pierce them at all! So in the case of thrown spears and of course arrows while they might generally be ineffective at killing large prey (unless it's a lucky shot) they can still be effective when used as described above.

Thanks for the bit of assistance.  By the way, the reason for such a rather ridiculously long winter is that the planet is at the edge of its host star's habitable zone, which makes it a good bit colder. And the 'can't pierce their hides' statement is partially false, because their weapons simply aren't sharp enough to pierce the Vrelniik's skin. The other seasons are spread out across the remaining 150 days of the Torenthelmi year. Fall/Autumn lasts 114 of their days, Summer is 20 days long, and Spring is pretty short, taking 16 days.

So, another edit, the Chitrant weapons aren't, with their current technology, strong enough to cut through Vrelniik pelt, but other creatures can be more easily slain, like the Llargthor, which is a bison-sized, omnivorous creature that they hunt for the large amounts of meat that they can use to bait other creature into their traps. Again, thank you for the ideas.

@ Ranger. With only Earths animals as a template? No large animal on earth is resistant to a sharp point that it runs through it's own body at speed. And the bigger the animal the worse the damage it its because their weight goes up in proportion to their surface volume CUBED. Look up the squared cube law. So say a dog running at 10mph on to a sharp stick is going to do itself a less serious injury than say a cow would doing the same thing all other factors being equal.

@Ranger just FYI a stone spearhead, humans most primitive technology, is the sharpest cutting edge in existance.

To put it in caveman terms, if you run with pointy stick at animal, it pierce more than just stabbing it because run fast make point dig more deep. And bigger animal means more damage.

As mentioned, knapped flint is absurdly sharp, and knapped obsidian is sharper still: far sharper than the sharpest metal scalpel we can produce. So sharpness is not the problem.
As for bow, late stone Age bows approached the sizes and power of modern hunting bow at about 50punds draw. That would be powerful enough to shoot an arrow through a tiger-sized monster.

To be fair to @Ranger, they aren't asserting that stone isn't sharp enough, they're asserting that stone isn't strong enough. Stone spearheads, however sharp, can't pierce through a sufficiently tough material. Whether it's realistic for hide to be that tough is a different question.

Mon has covered most of the obvious answers (and they are very good) - however there is one key one missing:
Slingshots and Staff Slings
The ancient slingshot was no joke - the story of David and Goliath is not mere biblical exaggeration - a stone flung from a proper slingshot is more than capable of being fatal to a human.
Staff slings added a wooden pole to allow for a heavier projectile weight. Some sources have that these were capable of slinging projectiles up to half a kilo at around 90 m/s.
To put that into perspective as to how much energy we are talking here - that is ~2000 joules of energy.
Or about the same amount of energy of an AK-47 round (7.62x39).
Your ancient hunters could use staff slings and heavy rocks and do an absolute number on these monsters.
Even if they don't pierce the skin, the blunt force trauma to the animal is going to break bones and damage organs or even a well aimed shot could cave in a skull.

And as we are talking staff-slings, lets not forget spear-throwers (atl-atl) which do the same thing but to a sharp spear. There are vidoes of mondern men one-shot killing a buffalo with a javelin from an atl-atl. Stone Age hunters who practiced all their lives would be even better at this.
Later in the Stone Age bows appear, and some of the late Mesolithic bows approached the size and power of the English Longbow. An arrow from one would go through a monster this size as if was made of styrofoam.

Yep, I've slung well over half a kilo stones with a staff sling, you can scale it up as well and have more than one person on the staff part and a lever (man powered portable trebuchet). Ancients used it as artillery

This is a great answer. a half-kilo stone out of a staff sling is a great resource against something that is hard to pierce.

Traps, traps, traps, and traps!
Large animals are very vulnerable to falling damage. A simple step down of one single meter is too much for an elephant. You can keep them enclosed with a simple relatively shallow ditch.
So you dig a ditch, or a hole, or use a natural one. And cover it up with vegetation. Lure the beast to it. It falls, breaking its bones. Then it will bleed out and die, no matter how invulnerable its skin is to your spears.

Traps? Considering how intelligent these creatures are, it might be a bit difficult to trap them. Still a good idea though.

@William Seeing as humanity manages to make booby traps which other humans fall for, it doesn't seem so strange it could work on merely 'smart animals' too.

Fair. So, thanks for the suggestion

Predators are smart. They kill to eat - and if the energy required to kill Chitrant is more than killing something else, they will hunt the easier prey. The best way to get them to go away is making attacks costly and time/energy consuming.
Unlike the Vrelniik, the Chitrant presumably have a class of full-time food producers supporting the Valenguard (which, by the way, is not accurate to Ice Age societies - they would never specialize like that). They do not need to do the same calorie math, and can engage in time-consuming and calorie-costly activities.
Such as fortification.
Bone shovels (and pickaxes)
Not even Alaska or Siberia experiences 300 day long winters (and presumably ~20 day long spring, summer, and fall?) except at the northernmost regions. Those regions are above what's called the "tree line" - the climate that is able to support trees.
Wood is going to be extremely rare and precious for your society. Bows and spears were historically popular because they were easy to manufacture with cheap materials that were at-hand. If you are fighting animals with skin so tough that spears and arrows can't penetrate it, those weapons are going to be breaking at an alarming rate, and replacing them will not be possible.
So you dig. Take the bones of the monsters that were successfully slain, and fashion them into entrenching tools. You are going to be building earthworks and digging pits (concealed with thin sheets of ice harvested from the sea, and lined with sharpened monster bones at the bottom). During the winter months, packed and frozen earth walls will be impenetrable, and Vrelniik leaping over them will find themselves in a pit and impaled.
Boulders
Gravity is your friend. Lug some boulders up onto the earthworks, and push them down onto attacking monsters - especially ones that have fallen into the pits. The blunt trauma doesn't need to penetrate their skin in order to juice their internal organs.

Impressive idea.

Bolas would likely be effective, especially in a massed attack.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolas

Ah yes, like when The Empire Struck Back! Not exactly stone age, but stone age methods ;-).

Good idea. Thanks.

For the win, make them explosive. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwjQ5l0VQ5s Or perhaps more realistically, give them sharp spikes.

Poison spears, darts, stoneblades. Toxin would depend but could be airless fermentation produced ,similar to botox.
